# Docker: Run an arbitrary command from inside a priveleged container on the host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a command from a priveleged docker. Specifically the command `nmcli`.

When I try to add `nmcli` as a volume, it complains that it's missing other files.

When I add the entire `/usr/bin` it complains about python being unable to add site-packages.

Is there a way, I can run a command on the host machine from a child container

Comment: Credit to @matt On my machine I needed an additional bind to run a more complex nmcli commands: docker run \ -v /lib:/lib \ -v /usr/lib/:/usr/lib \ -v /usr/bin/nmcli:/usr/bin/nmcli \ -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket \ --privileged \ ubuntu:16.04 \ /usr/bin/nmcli dev wifi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of tools that are installed with a package manager like `yum` or `apt` will make use of shared libraries to reduce the overall size of the install.

The container would either need to be the same distro and have the same package dependencies installed, or mount all the dependencies of the binary into the container.

Something like this should work:

```
docker run \
  -v /lib:/lib \
  -v /usr/lib/:/usr/lib \
  -v /usr/bin/nmcli:/usr/bin/nmcli \
  -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket \
  --privileged \
  busybox \
  /usr/bin/nmcli
```

But you might need to be more specific about the library mounts if you want the container to use it's own shared libraries as well.

Some packages can provide a "static binary" that include's all their dependencies in the executable. I doubt this exists for `nmcli` as it's a RHEL specific tool to manage a RHEL box, whose policy is to use yum to manage shared libraries.